# SQLAlchemy: Select rows, grouped by a date column, whose datetime column is most recent for each date

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Given the following table in a PostgreSQL database.

| value | created_at | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-02-01 01:01:01 | 2022-03-15 |
| 10 | 2022-02-15 01:01:01 | 2022-03-15 |
| 5 | 2022-02-02 01:01:01 | 2022-03-16 |
| 6 | 2022-02-16 01:01:01 | 2022-03-16 |

How can you write sqlalchemy code which:

1. Groups by the `date` column
2. Get's the most recent `created_at` value for each date
3. Returns all rows with meet that criteria

The output of above query should be the following:

| value | created_at | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2022-02-15 01:01:01 | 2022-03-15 |
| 6 | 2022-02-16 01:01:01 | 2022-03-16 |

I have tried the following query:

```py
query = (
            select(
                func.max(TABLE.created_at),
                TABLE.date,
                TABLE.value
            )
            .group_by(models.TABLE.date)
        )
```

But get the error
`"value" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

While, based on my understanding, using an aggregate function or including "value" in the GROUP BY clause will not provide the desired result.

What query can I use to get desired rows?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Im using PostgreSQL so any solution that would work with that would be appreciated

Comment: the solution is in the error message: the column "value" in your select must either appear in the group by clause or you need to use an aggregate function, such as max(value).

Comment: @RomanPurgstaller If "value" is included in the group by clause then the output will have more than 2 rows. Also an aggregate function (for example max) is used the the output will contain the max value for a given date, which may not be the correct value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the [distinct clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```py
query = select(TABLE).distinct(
            TABLE.date
        ).order_by(
            TABLE.date,
            TABLE.created_at.desc(),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at the project that I am doing, but after reading documentation about `relationships` and `distinct` i made this query.
You can also try like this, hope it helps.

```
query = (
         select value, created_at, date, count(distinct(date)) from TABLE group by value, created_at, date
        )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).